# Is boost::asio::deadline_timer thread safe?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to know that is `boost::asio::deadline_timer` thread safe?

Can somebody answer me?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be thread-safe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information you are looking for can be found in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html).

```
Thread Safety
Distinct objects: Safe.
Shared objects: Unsafe.
```